# Select top 5 and bottom 5 columns from a list of columns based on their values

Tags: t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to Select top 5 and bottom 5 columns from a list of columns based on their values.
If more than 1 column has same value then select any one from them.

Eg

```
CREATE TABLE #b(Company VARCHAR(10),A1 INt,A2 INt,A3 INt,A4 INt,B1 INt,G1 INt,G2 INt,G3 INt,HH5 INt,SS6 INt)

INSERT INTo #b
SELECT 'test_A',8,10,6,10,0,6,0,6,13,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'test_B',17,7,0,1,3,18,0,6,9,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'test_C',0,0,6,1,2,6,3,4,3,2 UNION ALL
SELECt 'test_D',13,1,4,1,4,1,9,0,0,5

SELECT * FROM #b
```

Desired Output:

| Company | Top5 | Bottom5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test_A | HH5,A2,A1,A3,SS6 | B1,SS6,A3,A1,A2 |
| test_B | G1,A1,HH5,A2,G3 | A3,A4,B1,SS6,G3 |

I am able to find the top values but not the column names.
Here is I am stuck at, I am able to find the max scores but not sure how to find the column that holds this max value.

```
SELECT Company,(
  SELECT MAX(myval) 
  FROM (VALUES (A1),(A2),(A3),(A4),(B1),(G1),(G2),(G3),(HH5)) AS temp(myval))
 AS MaxOfColumns
FROM #b
```

Comment: Expose the column names in your unpivot.

Comment: Could you send me a rough query?

Answer (score 1):

As Larnu suggested, the first step would be to `UNPIVOT` the data into a form like (Company, ColumnName, Value). You can then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign ordinals 1 - 10 to each value for each company based on the sorted value.

Next, you can wrap the above in a Common Table Expression (CTE) to feed a query that, for each Company, uses conditional aggregation with the `STRING_AGG()` to selectively combine the top 5 and bottom 5 column names to produce the desired result.

Something like:

```
;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
        Company,
        ColumnName,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Value DESC, ColumnName) AS Ord
    FROM #b
    UNPIVOT ( 
        Value FOR ColumnName IN (A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, G1, G2, G3, HH5, SS6)
    ) U
)
SELECT
    D.Company,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN D.Ord BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN D.ColumnName END, ', ')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.ORD) AS Top5,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN D.Ord BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN D.ColumnName END, ', ')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.ORD) AS Bottom5
FROM Data D
GROUP BY D.Company
ORDER BY D.Company
```

For older SQL Server versions  that don't support `STRING_AGG()`, the `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE` construct can be used to concatenate text. The `.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')` function is then used to safely extract the result from the XML, and finally the `STUFF()` function is used to strip out the leading separator (comma-space).

```
;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
        Company,
        ColumnName,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Value DESC, ColumnName) AS Ord
    FROM #b
    UNPIVOT ( 
        Value FOR ColumnName IN (A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, G1, G2, G3, HH5, SS6)
    ) U
)
SELECT B.Company, C.Top5, C.Bottom5
FROM #b B
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + D.ColumnName
            FROM Data D
            WHERE D.Company = B.Company
            AND D.Ord BETWEEN 1 AND 5
            ORDER BY D.ORD
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Top5,
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + D.ColumnName
            FROM Data D
            WHERE D.Company = B.Company
            AND D.Ord BETWEEN 6 AND 10
            ORDER BY D.ORD
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Bottom5
) C
ORDER BY B.Company
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TXmHS7q9) fr a demo.

If you also want lists of the top 5 and bottom 5 values, you can repeat the aggregations above while substituting `CONVERT(VARCHAR, D.Value)` for `D.ColumnName` where appropriate.

Comment: @harshac If this answer serves your needs, can you mark the answer as accepted?